# React - props does not update in entire component the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

SOLVED!

componentDidUpdate() was what I needed! Thanks for help!

This will be a question from really React newbie.

The idea of component that I've got a problem with is about creating a buttons that behave like online store 'buy' button - when clicked, the item is added to a 'basket' and button is disabled, but when removed, item is ereased from the list, and button should be enabled back.

With the last part I have a problem. I decided that each button will be enabled/disabled on condition wheather it is on this.props.chosenModulesNames list or not. If it is I'm updating a state. It works nicely with adding items to the list but removing is a little bit harder to me.

What I've found so far, that this.props.chosenModules are updating dynamic in render method, but are not before that. How can I solve this problem? (Maybe lifecycle methods is the answer?)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class AddModule extends Component {
  state = {
    disabled: false,
    moduleDisplayInfo: "Add module",
    chosenModulesNames: this.props.chosenModulesNames
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddModuleToList = this.handleAddModuleToList.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddModuleToList() {
    {
      /*In here this.props.chosenModulesNames does not update dynamicly
            */
      //console.log(this.props.chosenModulesNames);
    }
    this.props.moveModuleNameUpToSingleModule(this.props.name);
    this.props.chosenModulesNames.includes(this.props.name)
      ? this.setState({
          disabled: true,
          moduleDisplayInfo: "Added"
        })
      : this.setState({
          disabled: false,
          moduleDisplayInfo: "Add module!"
        });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/*Here this.props.chosenModulesNames are actual and dynamic updated*/}
        {console.log(this.props.chosenModulesNames)}

        <Button
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
          bsStyle="primary"
          onClick={this.handleAddModuleToList}
        >
          {this.state.moduleDisplayInfo}
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddModule;
```

EDIT:
codesandbox.io/s/pmqlwy2w5q -> this may be more helpful. Major problem is that after removing element from 'Shopping list' I want a button related to it's element to be enabled back. I think that 'addModule.jsx' component is crucial in here. I also logged a props that I'm willing to use in my conditional statement: one in render method, that would be usefull for me beacuse it's dynamic; and the same props within a handleAddModuleToList method that it's not working the same as the first one. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to do a check in `componentWillReceiveProps` to see if `chosenModulesNames` has updated. If your `AddModule` component is not re-rendering each time something is added or removed from the basket, it will never know about prop updates unless you specifically check for them. You would need to do something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.chosenModulesNames !== nextProps.chosenModulesNames) {
        this.handleAddModuleToList(nextProps);
    }
}
```

Notice I am passing nextProps into the function as well. I suggest you pass props in as an argument to the `handleAddModuleToList` func because you won't be getting the latest props but just accessing props internally in the function. When you are comparing `this.props` vs `nextProps` it obviously may not be as straight forward as checking for equality if `chosenModulesNames` is an object. In `render()` you would also want to update `onClick` to pass in props there too:

```
    <Button
      disabled={this.state.disabled}
      bsStyle="primary"
      onClick={this.handleAddModuleToList(this.props)}
    >
```

Then remove references to `this.props` in your function so that it's referencing the props argument you are passing into the function now.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pmqlwy2w5q -> this may be more helpful. Major problem is that after removing element from 'Shopping list' I want a button related to it's element to be enabled back. I think that 'addModule.jsx' component is crucial in here. I also logged a props that I'm willing to use in my conditional statement: one in render method, that would be usefull for me beacuse it's dynamic; and the same props within a handleAddModuleToList method that it's not working the same as the first one. Any idea?

Comment: You are over-engineering this a bit. Why not just observe the props changing instead of keeping track twice with state? See this edited version of your codesandbox in `addModule.jsx`. Just make the `disabled` prop on `Button` a function that checks if the option is in the list or not. It'll always update if props ever change https://codesandbox.io/s/q75nvwnr3w

Comment: Austin! You're my hero! It was so simple, so easy! I cope with that problem in other way but...Your proposition is much better! Thanks a lot for your time and advice!